# Why is my code not printing all the values given in the dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a function where it provides all the details of a car. The function takes manufacturer, model and arbitrary no. of arguments and stores in dictionary. When I am providing the arbitrary values in my function call it only prints one value out of three values provided.

This is for linux mint 19.1 cinnamon-geany Ide

```
def car(manufacturer,Model, **features):
    """Details of the car"""
    car_profile={}
    car_profile['manufacturer']= manufacturer
    car_profile['Model']= Model
    for key, value in features.items():
        car_profile[key]=value
        return car_profile
car_info=car('honda', 'accord', year=1991, color='white',
        headlights='popup')
print(car_info)
```

The result should display all the key-value pairs in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You return you car_profile in the for loop. What you want to do is

```
def car(manufacturer,Model, **features):
    """Details of the car"""
    car_profile={}
    car_profile['manufacturer']= manufacturer
    car_profile['Model']= Model
    for key, value in features.items():
        car_profile[key]=value
    return car_profile
```